# Magento Admin panel - On page attribute set does not work "Add group"

Tags: javascript, magento, admin

I can't add groups in my admin panel. I found, that there js error, when I click on "add group" button.

**Error :** `"Uncaught ReferenceError: editSet is not defined ".`

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and found two (not very elegant) solutions // magento 1.8.

1. There seems to be some problem with admin translation that causes this problem. So just change your admin language ( at the bottom of the admin page ) to something like english (ireland).
2. This problem is in some cases caused by conflicting versions of jQuery. Try to temporarily change the setting `merge js files` located under system->config->developer->javascript settings.